# jquery hover only works on home page (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the site that I'm working on: [test site](http://sitetest.site90.net/)

"Quotes" in the navigation has a submenu that appears on hover. But once you scroll down the page, the submenu stops working right.

Here's my jQuery code, only the first chunk pertains to the submenu but I'm including the rest in case you find a conflict:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Dropdown Submenu

    $(function(){

        $("nav ul li").hover(
            function(){
                $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');            
        },  function(){     
                $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

        });

    });

    // Smooth Scroll

    $('a[href*=#]').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top}, 1000);
            return false;
    });

    // Header Shadow

    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var a = 5;
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(pos > a) {
        $('header').addClass('bottom-shadow');
    }
    else {
        $('header').removeClass('bottom-shadow');
    }
    });


});
```

The html:

```
<nav>..
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#services">Services</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#providers">Providers</a> </li>  
        <li> <a href="#plans">Plans</a> </li>                  
        <li> <a href="#quotes">Quotes</a> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#indiv">Individual / Family</a></li>
                <li><a href="#group">Business / Group</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#contact">Contact</a> </li>                    
    </ul>                     
</nav>
```

The CSS:

```
nav ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 22px;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li{
  float: left;
  zoom: 1;
}
nav ul li a{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #304F70;
}
nav ul ul{ 
  width: 180px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 16px; 
  left: 270px; 
}
nav ul ul li{   
  font-weight: normal; 
  background: url(../images/white_texture_bg.jpg), repeat, #FFF;
  color: #000; 
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #B4AFAB; 
  float: none; 
}
nav ul ul li:last-child{
  border-bottom: none;
}             
nav ul ul li a{ 
  border-right: none; 
  width: 100%; 
  display: inline-block; 
  text-align: left;
}
```

Please help me figure out what the problem is.  Thanks!

**Edited:**   Not working right in Chrome, but works ok in Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Not able to duplicate the problem. I scroll down the window and hover and it still works...

Comment: Looks like the problem happens in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After delete the `main` element, it works.

EDIT:

The relationship between `main` and `header` is same level, so you should change your structure to:

```
<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <main>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: You’re right!  I dug a little deeper into this and it seems that the main element had a class with the property "-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;”.  This was leftover from a plugin I played around with earlier.  I took that out and the problem is gone. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out this link: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/hover-not-working-for-chrome

It appears that there are issues with the .hover function in jQuery for chrome. I believe your function

```
  $("nav ul li").hover(
        function(){
            $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');            
    },  function(){     
            $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

    });
```

still may be getting triggered since when you scroll, there are many different "ul li" throughout the page that you are default 'hovering' over such that this bit of code is called: $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden'); adding an id to the elements you need to access  may inherently  solve this issue.

Comment: I did try adding a class earlier to the ul and modified the jQuery code accordingly, but that didn't solve the problem.  Anyway, thanks for taking the time to answer!